# &#353; and other char not visible

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm be wild about some CZECH char. On DB I've saved strings with č (and similar chars) and I'm able to show this only if I set my page charset to ISO-8859-1.

It could be ok, but I've an UTF-8 XML file and when I try to get some string from this xml I've some problem. Basically the string from XML will not be shown correctly if I use ISO-8859-1 charset. The xml is UTF-8. I've tried to convert č and similiar char to &#353;  on xml and using ISO-8859-1 charset but they won't be shown correctly.

So. The situation is:

XML on UTF-8 and HTML Page with UTF-8, string from XML correct but string from DB not visible
XML on ISO-8859-1 and HTML Page with UTF-8, string from XML not correct but string from DB correct

I've also tried to convert XML string with ICONV or similar funciont but nothing happens.

Could you help me, please?

Andrea

Comment: `iconv()` should be the solution. Can you provide more details on what you tried and how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: č in ISO-8859-1? are you sure? I don't see it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#ISO-8859-1

Comment: with ISO-8859-1 I can see this char correctly

Comment: @Andrea Girardi Probably the browser ignores that and uses ISO-8859-13 or some windows codepage.

Comment: This page fornacigrigolin.it/slo/Home.php is ISO-8859-1 and the text title is UTF-8. With iconv the ž char is cutted

Comment: @Artefacto I've tried with windows-1250 (I take a look to some national SK website) but I've the same error getting char from UTF-8

Comment: this is the xml file http://www.fornacigrigolin.it/include/SLO.xml

Comment: @Andrea Girardi So the page's UTF-8, the XML file is UTF-8... The only problem is the DB, right? If you're using MySQL try executing `SET NAMES UTF8`, if postgresql `SET client_encoding TO ' UTF8'`, etc. and make sure the data in the DB is stored correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of functions that convert UTF8 to ISO-8859-1, including PHP's [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). However I would strongly advise to use UTF8 where possible. Also, whenever a character question is asked, [this article](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a must-read.

Comment: This page http://www.fornacigrigolin.it/slo/Home.php is ISO-8859-1 and the text title is UTF-8. With mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1'); you can see the result. Page title is wrong
(it has to be "Vodilna italianska firma izdelkov za gradbenižtvo")